# How is a part of eulerian path called?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, eulerian-path

An eulerian path in a graph is a path that visits every edge in the graph exactly once.

If there is a path that has a similar property that it visits an edge at most once (e.g. a part of an eulerian path has this property), is there a name for such path (like "eulerian" is for the one described above)?

Comment: Not every path that visits an edge at most once is necessarily a part of an Eulerian path

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Could you please show me a (counter-)example? I can't imagine one just now. (Just out of curiosity, it is not entirely relevant for the question itself :).)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I see now. I'm editting the question right now.

Comment: A path that visits an edge at most once is called a path. There is no other kind of path because, by definition, a path is a walk with no repeated vertices (or edges). Now, if you wanted a name for a **walk** with no repeated edges, that is sometimes called a trail.

Comment: @bof Silly me, I always mix up what path, walk and trail actually mean (since I'm not in english speaking country and we use our terms which I mix too). But then "eulerian path" is a wrong (even [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path)) term and "eulerian trail" or "eulerian walk" should be used instead, shouldn't they?

Comment: Not necessarily, some books use _simple_ path if no vertex was used twice, and just path for the rest. If there is no contex, it's best to state/clarify the terms you are using. In other words, rather than looking for some fancy terms, just _precisely_ (in words) describe what you want.